# time series cross validation and avoidance of overfitting

Tags: time-series, classification, cross-validation, regularization, dropout

So. I am doing Time Series Classification on various datasets using different types of classifiers (deep learning, dictionary-based, distance-based, interval-based, feature-based, convolution). As far as I know, k-fold is not a good option for time series, so I've switched to TimeSeriesSplit.

However, overfitting is not ensured, of course, even when doing cross-validation. K-fold solves this problem by shuffling, but TimSeriesSplit doesn't do that (that's the point, actually). I would use Dropout Layers or Regularization, but these techniques are only for deep-learning models, and my goals basically is to compare the results of all these algorithms altogether. What would be a good technique to use for all types of classifiers, in my case?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated? Doesn't a time series split result in training on some in-sample time period ("the past") and test on some out-of-sample time period ("the future")? Isn't that exactly what you want to be able to do, to predict if stocks will go up or down tomorrow instead of last Thursday (which you can look up)?